# Sci fi book identification from Mars to Jupiter?

Tags: story-identification, mars

So I was reading a sci-fi book that started on Mars (it was in my old job's break room; I moved jobs and can't remember the name). I only recall bits and pieces and didn't get far. Any help in identifying the book would be great. See below for what I remember.

1. The main character was a married female scientist that was leading research on Mars.
2. Hubby was also a lead scientist and discovered that a giant Martian life form responds to radio waves/electric pulses (in one part they basically go caving inside this creature.)
3. Young hot shot ends up crashing a wing suit in a publicity stunt on a news recording to Earth (the science/research base relies on publicity to secure funding)
4. In part due to this they get a stick in the mud admin type that is going to take over running the Mars facility, but this is actually a ploy by the bigwig funding the whole thing to get them to agree to head to a new planet that has yet to be explored (Jupiter I think?)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters?  What was on Jupiter (or whatever planet) that was more interesting than Martian life?  Do you recall the cover of the book?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Life ?
If not that, you may want to peruse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Novels_set_on_Mars

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like *The Martian Race* or possibly its sequel *The Sunborn*, by Gregory Benford. The "other planet" is Pluto.

I have lent the book to a friend and cannot check, but I seem to remember the wing suit stunt, and surely the subterranean expedition "inside" the creature.

Comment: A goodreads review mentions "Julia almost suffocating as she lowers herself into a Martian vent to explore some misting that might indicate an ancient harbor for life eons past", so there's the caving bit.